# when search string is null how can i bring my previews data?

Tags: c#, xml

i have created a search method to get a specific object.Detial  and show it in my datagrid. it works just fine.

```
    internal ObservableCollection<Request> GetSearched(string s)
    {
        var rusult = new ObservableCollection<Request>();
        
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        {
            foreach (var row in GetRequests())
            {
                rusult.Add(row);
            }
            return rusult;
        }
        else
        {
            rusult.Clear();
            foreach (var row in GetRequests().Where(retrive => retrive.Detail.Contains(s)))
            {
                rusult.Add(row);
            }
        }   
        return rusult;

    }
```

but the sting is empty or just a white space it wont return to my previews datagrid data!!. how can i make it work ?

Comment: Remove `if` branch.

Answer (score 0):

can you clarify what you mean with

> it wont return to my previews datagrid data

Do you want to save and retrieve your previous search request? or just all requests?
Does it return anything at the moment if the string s is empty?

It looks like it returns everything if string is empty.

Comment: if i type something in the sting s it return what i searched for,but when i make the s sting empty still it return what i searched for not everything was in the datagrid.